# Why can I move out of mutable self reference for Read?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I can't figure out why this code compiles:

```rust
use std::io::{Read, BufRead};

trait ReadString {
    fn read_null_terminated_string(&mut self, max_size: u64) -> std::io::Result<String>;
}

impl<R> ReadString for R
where
    R: BufRead,
{
    fn read_null_terminated_string(&mut self, max_size: u64) -> std::io::Result<String> {
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        self.take(max_size).read_until(0, &mut buf)?;
        Ok(String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf).to_string())
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell `BufRead` is not `Copy`, and `BufRead::take()` is:

```rust
    fn take(self, limit: u64) -> Take<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Take { inner: self, limit }
    }
```

So surely the `.take()` should move `self`, which is not allowed because I only have `&mut self`? I even tried with my own `BufRead`-like trait and I did get this error:

```
cannot move out of `*self` which is behind a mutable reference
move occurs because `*self` has type `R`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

So why don't I get that error with `BufRead`?

Comment: It does move `self`, but `self` is `&mut T`

Comment: It does not compile https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a77819b1615c96bda24ee7ca305fb07

Comment: Ahhh because it has `impl<R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &mut R`. Confusing!

Comment: @pigeonhands You also need to `use std::io::Read` apparently, so it gets that `impl<R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &mut R`.

Comment: you unlock the level 3 of Rust, `self` can be a mutable reference, congratulation :p thus I have no idea what are other level since I just made this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not invoking `take()` on type `Self`, you are invoking it on type `&mut Self` (the type of the `self` parameter) and it indeed consumes it. This works because [`Read` has a blanket implementation `impl<R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &mut R`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.66.0/src/std/io/impls.rs.html#17-52).